# Defered return of an async function in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) (library to create pdf in javascript) in my angularJS app. pdfmake uses an asynchronous function to create the pdf blob.

So what I'm trying to do is create a function that can return an array of pdf blobs. I tried the following:

```
createMultiplePDF: function(objects) {
    var p = $q.when();

    var retObjects = [];
    angular.forEach(objects, function(pdfObject, index) {
        p = p.then(function (formerRes) {
            return pdfMake.createPdf(objects[index].pdf).getBuffer(function(slipPdfObject){
               retObjects.push(angular.copy(slipPdfObject));
            });
        });

    });
    return p.then(function(){
        return retObjects;
    });
}
```

But I get an empty array... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getBuffer` does not return a promise, does it?

Comment: I don't think so...it returns just a blob

Comment: You mean, it passes it asynchronously to the callback?

Comment: yes... to be honnest, I'm a bit lost with asynchronous functions and defered promise! What I need is a promise or a callback so I can use the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my approach in your case:

```
createMultiplePDF: function(objects) {

  var retObjects = [];
  angular.forEach(objects, function(pdfObject, index) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();      
      pdfMake.createPdf(objects[index].pdf).getBuffer(function(slipPdfObject){
        deferred.resolve(angular.copy(slipPdfObject));
      });
      retObjects.push(deferred.promise);
  });
  var pdfList = $q.all(retObjects);
  return pdfList;
}
```

Comment: when I call this: createMultiplePDF(slipsTpl).then(function (pdfObjects) {          I get an error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined